# javascript custom function for changing dates

Tags: javascript, function, date

I have a trouble with a custom function that I've done.

In fact it does not work and I really do not know why.

Here is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lz(x){
    return x.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/,'0$1')
}
function dayplus(){
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    if (items[i].getAttribute('required')){
      var itemDtParts = items[i].value.split("-");
      var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ +nb);
      items[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear();
    }
  }
}
​</script>
```

It says to me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL addday.html:20
```

Moreover it says to me that the function is undefined or it is not the case.

Here below is the form I use with the function:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" required value="26-10-2012">

<input type="button" value="( - )" width="22" height="22" onClick="subday()" />
                  <input name="jours" type="text" value="" size="5" id="nb" />
                  <input type="button" value="( + )" width="22" height="22" onClick="dayplus()"  />​​​​​
```

Comment: var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10)+ +nb); what's this var nb ( var nb=document.getElementsById('id') ) then there is an extra + !! isn't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyP6X/). changes: `nb` was missing, you were using `+ +` to add `nb`

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" required=true value="26-10-2012">

<input type="button" value="( - )" width="22" height="22" onClick="subday()" />
                  <input name="jours" type="text" value="" size="5" id="nb" />
<input type="button" value="( + )" width="22" height="22" onClick="dayplus()"  />


<script type="text/javascript">
function lz(x){
     return x.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/,'0$1');
}
function dayplus(){
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker hasDatepicker");
     nb = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    if (items[i].getAttribute('required')){
      var itemDtParts = items[i].value.split("-");

      var itemDt  = new Date(itemDtParts[2], parseInt(itemDtParts[1] ,10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10) +nb);

      items[i].value = lz(itemDt.getDate())+"-"+lz(itemDt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+itemDt.getFullYear();

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you verry much for the reply. But Actually it does not worl like previous function. Because If I do 5 days or whatever number it does not add the real number for example if I do  nb = document.getElementById("nb").value; it does not work

Comment: use:  nb = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb").value);

Comment: Depend on your requirement. if output depends on nb then you should. and if always going to +1/-1. you should use +1/-1.

Comment: dear Sir thanks for your quick reply. I just would ask if there is a way to add a zero before the day if it is <10 ? because sometimes I have 1-10-2012 I would like to have 01-10-2012 . Kind Regards

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I modified your lz function. that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d8mdb/)

The first thing I noticed, is that your markup looks strange. Shouldn't it be

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" required="true" value="26-10-2012">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" required value="26-10-2012">
```

The second thing is the invalid syntax, as pointed out by enhzflep and Kimo_do, `nb` is not defined and `+ + nb`. I replaced it by `1` in the fiddle.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've corrected this. Line 20 is </script>

Comment: Dear Sir I tried to replace the +1 by   var nb = document.getElementById("nb").value; but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

`,10)+ +nb);` should be `,10)+ nb);` perhaps? or `,10)+ (+nb) );` if nb may be negative. That is to say - it looks like an added +. On closer looking, I'm also wondering if you actually mean nb.value or it's longhand: document.getElementById('nb').value?

Or in code:

```
var itemDt  = new Date(parseInt(itemDtParts[2],10), parseInt(itemDtParts[1],10)-1, parseInt(itemDtParts[0],10) + document.getElementById('nb').value) );
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you so much for the reply. I've tried with your correction but now it says to me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL addday.html:20
Uncaught ReferenceError: dayplus is not defined addday.html:29

Comment: Youre welcome. Bit hard to say what the problem is without seeing all code from lines 1-20 inclusive.